# Translation of a long phrase 但便捷的本质 并不是让你的麻烦凭空消失 而是另一个特定的群体 替你经历了

Tags: translation

Can you guys tell me the meaning of this sentences in english
Its about a love story from a book. And the rich guy just gave the girl of gifts/money ( i dont know if its relevant) but the girl posted this probably for the guy to see.
Is it. A good or a bad sign? Thank you

但便捷的本质 
并不是让你的麻烦凭空消失 
而是另一个特定的群体 
替你经历了

Also the girl hinted that she is testing this guy if he is a suitable partner for herself (i dont know if its relevant abot the sentences also)

Comment: There is nothing relevant to the story you are addressing here.

Comment: So whats the meaning of the Chinese sentences? Its a story

Comment: Roughly, it says the essence of shortcut or convenient and fast way is that  trouble wouldn't gone away literarily, but endured by others for you. It conveys that your trouble in front of you would not disappear and someone else has done the work for you so that you are easy to get through. It encourages people to do the work or overcome their own difficulties(otherwise someone has to deal with them for you).

Comment: Bad signal, the girl doesn't agree with the boy's value. I don't think that the girl want to give a chance to the boy.  No pains no gains.

Answer (score 1):

It basically means:

> The essence of convenience is not to make troubles disappear but to
>   transfer troubles to others who would solve them for you

It is a bad sign.  It means that the girl thinks that the guy thinks money can solve any problem and does not see the effort of others who are paid to do the work.

Comment: BUt this girl keeps on accepting the gifts maybe shes telling it to herself and not the guy?

Comment: By the way she posted it with a heart above the message. Thus giving me the idea that shes telling herself she needs to work hard and not just rely on the guy?

Comment: @epiconside no, by saying this, she expressed her dissatisfaction (maybe the gift is not chosen/made by the guy himself?).  But she accept the gift for realistic reasons (economical benefit).  I don't think it is a word for herself as a Chinese.

Comment: We can't tell unless we could find more evidence.

Comment: This guy was beside her during when she was sick pick her up when she was on another state at midnigt twice! The giy on the book is rich but has a good heart this girl was a miss universe in China a traditional girl. Are you sure this guy is to blame for?

Comment: And who gives a gift made by themselves these days? No seriously? Usually you buy a jewelry not made it by yourself

Comment: also the guy is also a Chinese but grew up abroad so he cant speak that much correct Chinese...okay

Comment: Any other context the girl has posted besides this? The post is odd without any background to support it.

Comment: @epiconside it is a complicated mix of anti-rich altitude, hate of power of capital and pursue of wealth.

Comment: @epiconside in Japanese, it might be described by the word ツンデレ though not very accurate

Comment: If the guy can not speak Chinese well, the girl wouldn't expect him to understand that complicated sentence here. Hence, it shouldn't be written for him.

Comment: Thanks guys but i think this girl is a psycho i mean from the book thanks anyways

Comment: rich people arr people also by the way they just work harder than normal and poor people!